# Android application communication encryption with Java Server

Tags: java, android, spring, ssl, encryption

I have created a android application which is communicating with my java server(REST) which is based on Spring boot. Currently the communication is based on http so there is no encryption, I want to encrypt the communication using SSL.

I have created a key store and added certificate to it via keytool. Im able to access the service via browser using HTTPS but Im unable to do so via the android application. The application is using okhttp client for communication.

How can I access the service via HTTPS on my android application?

Comment: Use a certificate that is signed by a trusted certificate authority.

Comment: I develop this software as a project for my University course so I need to use the toolkit which allows me to use free certificate.

Comment: Then use Let's Encrypt.  It's free.